# What fonts do I need to install for special characters to work?

Tags: fonts

What fonts do I need to install on Ubuntu in order to see special characters ( for example)?

Comment: Please provide some more information. Where did you find these fonts? Any website?

Comment: In Wikipedia, in the languages section

Comment: This isn't a "font" issue, this is an encoding issue.

Comment: I can't see the cyrillic alphabet in the russian pages, and the japanese alphabet too

Comment: Provide a link to the page.

Comment: This is obviously encoding.

Comment: It will be more useful if you provide a screenshot or an image of the characters that you are referring to because of in the majority of the cases it looks like an encoding issue but you may be meaning the usage of a font in a different software, other than the web browser. If that's the case, please provide a screenshot in order to receive the proper support. Good luck and welcome to the Askubuntu.

Comment: Here is a screenshot http://ubuntuone.com/7mzvtWMJBPEpjeRvEL9s5R in http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caballo

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well apparently this was a "fonts" problem for specific languages.

Visit this Wikipedia page: [List of ISO 639-1 codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) and check the languages that aren't working for you.

I had the same issue for the Tibetan language which were showing those squares instead of the actual character. Installing the package `fonts-tibetan-machine` fixed the problems for that exact language.

```
sudo apt-get install fonts-tibetan-machine
```

So in order to fix the other languages, you need to install the necessary font package for that language.